# Error while deploying web application using NetBeans 8.0.2 and tomcat 8. What should I do?

Tags: netbeans-8, tomcat8

Here I am attaching netbeans IDE error window. I am facing problem when running web application using netbeans 8.0.2 and tomcat 8. When I run application it is showing "The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details."

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Screenshoting a text is not the best idea. Better copy-and-paste the text itself. And also add some details about your code: in which configuration was it working before, what has been changed, etc.

Comment: C:\Users\pcw\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 38 seconds)         -    This is error on console

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and this solved it;

- Download and unzip: [Apache tomcat 8.0.39](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi#8.0.39)
- add the Apache tomcat server to your project
- Then go to; Netbeans -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings -> select "No Proxy" option  (i guess you're using MacOsx)

Note: I tried the same thing with Apache tomcat 8.5.9 but it doesn't work.

Good luck...!